# ERROR: variable "string" is not initialized

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I wrote this code that reads from a .txt a string and settles it in a char *, but it gives me error that the variable "string" is not initialized, even if i initialized it inside the fscanf, can u tell me where i wrong? Thanks!

```
    char *string;
    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", string);
```

Comment: You must allocate some space to `string`.

Comment: well, if i dont know how is long the string in the txt file? How i allocate enough space for it? Thanks

Comment: `string` is a pointer to `char`. You've to make it point to a `char` array(`char buffer[100]; string = buffer;`) or dynamically allocate memory(`string = malloc(100);` and after use, `free(string);`) before you write to it from the `fscanf`.

Comment: If you don't know how long the text is then you have options.  One is to figure out a maximum, 4096 is a common one used for a maximum line length.  Second, don't use `fscanf`, use `fread` where you can specify the maximum number of bytes to read.  That's a bit more work, but safer.

Comment: @wing , In that case, you can use `getline` if you can. It allocates the right amount of memory.

Comment: `getline` is GNU/POSIX, so compiler/environment dependant.  `fgets()` ?

Comment: @cdarke: surely you are not suggesting to use `fread` on a plain text file? You may be confusing it with `fgets` (even with that, it depends on unknown reasons why OP chose to use `fscanf`).

Comment: the source code for getline is available online.   download it, compile it, use the resulting object as part of your executable.  here is one source: <http://opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-29/cvs/lib/getline.c>

Comment: @Jongware i use fscanf cause it seems me the fastest way to get a string from a file.
Then fgets reeds only until the \n instead the \0 of the fscanf.

Comment: @Jongware:  no, I wasn't confusing it with `fgets()`.  We do not know the format of the text file, it could be Unicode for all we know.  `fgets()` can be fun on a utf-8 file.

Comment: @cdarke: please expand on that. You can't be worried about getting zero bytes (as these are as illegal in UTF8 as they are in plain text) or accidentally parsing a return as 'part of a UTF8 character' or the other way around (because per definition of UTF8 neither can happen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, you didn't allocate string. C needs you to allocate it in memory before you use it. Also you will have to know its size.

In your code, string points to nowhere into memory so it doesn't exist (to be exact it points to somewhere you have a lot of chance that you can't access it)

See how malloc works.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate space for the string with malloc function.

```
string=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: BTW, `malloc` is a function. "malloc statement" is a wrong statement.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain where the `100` comes from?

Comment: I just used 100 as an example.We can allocate as much memory as we feel safe to work with.